# Update WPF with externalevent and MVVM schema

Tags: c#

I'm currently developping a new soft which analyze a lot of data on Revit.
I have my WPF View, my ViewModel and a long methode.

init.cs:

```
IExternalEventHandler handlerEvent = new FamilyAnalysis();
var familyAnalysisEvent = ExternalEvent.Create(handlerEvent);
Gui = new AnalysisView(familyAnalysisEvent);
Gui.Show();
```

AnalysisView.xaml.cs:

```
public AnalysisView(ExternalEvent externalEvent)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Windows.SetLocation(this);
    Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
    DataContext = new AnalysisViewModel(externalEvent, this);
}
```

AnalysisViewModel.cs:

```
public ICommand StartAnalysisCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _startAnalysisCommand ?? (_startAnalysisCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            //Some check before then..
            _externalEvent.Raise();
        }));
    }
}
```

during the _externalEvent.Raise() I would like to have a loading form updating the state of the methode.

I tried to search about dispatcher but I'm not sure how to do that and all my try didn't worked. The loading screen pop but the value are not getting updated.

Any advice ?